# When you start a finished project downloaded from the internet Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: flutter

When creating a new app in Android Studio, everything starts normally. But if you download an example of some kind, then the application does not start and shows an infinite download, how to fix it? That is, I downloaded a ready-made project, try to run it, and show me the Running Gradle task `assembleDebug` and nothing else happens. But if I create a new project myself, it starts. Could it be because I didn't install Dart and Flutter separately? and I installed them through Android Studio and use them

this is a ready-made project that I downloaded from the internet and it does not start. It doesn't show any errors.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dart comes with Flutter. So, you don't need to install them both separately.
Since there is no error, it means that it is just slow. What happens is that the first build requires a lot of files. Some of the packages need to be downloaded and certain files needed to be built. So, it will take time. The speed may also be affected by the internet speeds.
In your case, when you're creating a new project. It is a basic project. So, very few files. So, it gets done quicker.

Comment: I waited for 10 minutes. I'll try to wait a little longer, but it's weird. The project is not very big, I would say small too.

Comment: Well, in my PC, it takes around 15-20 minutes to run the project. Sometimes, even more. Slow PC can cause this.

Comment: Understood. Tell me another such problem, in an attempt to solve the past, a new one has appeared. Reinstalled Android Studio, installed the Flutter and Dart plugins. But doesn't show the "new Flutter project" menu item ? and when flutter doctor writes that the plugins are not installed, although they have been installed several times.

Comment: The absence or presence of Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio are not much of a problem. You can create those projects through VS Code as well. Also, you can look for solutions on StackOverflow for the same. I saw one similar error last week.